# javascript/php redirect to app store from facebook app

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

after updated facekbook app on 01 july 2015.
redirect to app store from facebook app is not working for me.

i have 2 redirect pages on my server like next flow.

```
<html><head></head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            window.location.href='https://itunes.apple.com/app/id';
            // or window.open('https://itunes.apple.com/app/id');
        });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

AND

```
<?php
 header('Location: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id', 301);
 exit;
?>
```

it was working before updated facebook app.

problem is when links click on facebook app, it's open from facebook in app web browser.
and it asked me 'leave from facebook app?' when i clicked leave. it's showikng blank page.

is it facebook app's problem? or can i have a solution?

Comment: location.href='itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id'; also not working.

Comment: What do you mean update Facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

Add ob_start and session_start for header function and close ob_start with ob_end_flush

Ex:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
 header('Location: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id', 301);
 exit;
ob_end_flush();
?>
```